# Any quick way to labelize a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of 200k elements. Those elements are 7 different labels (it is actually a list of fruit). I need to assign a number to each fruit.

Is there a quick way to do this?

I have written this so far.. and it is taking ages.

```
dic,i = {},0.0
for idx,el in enumerate(listFruit):
    if dic.has_key(el) is not True:
        dic[el] = i
        i+=1.0
    listFruit[idx] = dic[el]
```

Comment: You mean you want to assign a unique number to each fruit?

Comment: Yes. Apple should be 1 always, Banana 2 Strawberry 3.... till ananas 7.

Comment: Note: `has_key` is deprecated. To check if a key is in a dictionary use `key in dictionary`. In your case: `if el not in dic`. Also I have no idea why you are assigning floating point numbers....

Comment: It s because I want to do a smoothie. lol. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Dirty_Fox: your posted code suggests you should start counting at `0.0`, not `1`, and that it is the order in which you find the fruit in the list first that determines the count (so `Apple` will be `0.0` only if that is the first unique fruit encountered).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with an [`itertools.count()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) rigged up as to produce a next value as the factory; this'll avoid having to test for each key yourself as well as having to manually increment.

Then use a list comprehension to put those numbers into the list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial
from itertools import count

unique_count = defaultdict(partial(next, count(1)))
listFruit[:] = [unique_count[el] for el in listFruit]
```

The [`functools.partial()` callable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) creates a wrapper around the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next), to ensure the code works in either Python 2 or Python 3.

I used an integer count here, starting at `1`. You can replace `count(1)` with `count(1.0)` if you insist on having floating point values; you'll get `1.0`, `2.0`, `3.0`, etc. instead.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from functools import partial
>>> from itertools import count
>>> from random import choice
>>> fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'cherry', 'melon', 'kiwi', 'pineapple']
>>> listFruit = [choice(fruits) for _ in xrange(100)]
>>> unique_count = defaultdict(partial(next, count(1)))
>>> [unique_count[el] for el in listFruit]
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 7, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 7, 3, 5, 1, 3, 3, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 6, 2, 1, 1, 3, 6, 6, 4, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5, 2, 1, 7, 7, 7, 4, 3, 7, 3, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 6, 5, 6, 1, 4, 3, 7, 2, 7, 7, 4, 7, 1, 4, 3, 7, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 6, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 7, 2, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 1, 6, 5, 4]
>>> unique_count
defaultdict(<functools.partial object at 0x1026c5788>, {'kiwi': 4, 'apple': 1, 'cherry': 5, 'pear': 2, 'pineapple': 6, 'melon': 7, 'banana': 3})
```

Comment: `partial(next, count(1))` works both in python2 and 3. Or `lambda: next(count(1))`

Comment: @Bakuriu: yes, thanks. I was debating wether or not to further complicate matters here (in terms of cognitive load). I prefer `partial()` since it avoids dropping back into Python code too much.

Comment: Wait the lambda one should be `c = count(1); lambda: next(c)` otherwise it is a constant function

Comment: @Bakuriu: `lambda c=count(1): next(c)` would do too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'watermelon','apple','watermelon']

unique_fruits = [x for x in set(fruit_list)]
fruit_dict = dict((unique_fruits[y],y) for y in range(len(unique_fruits)))
result = [(x, fruit_dict.get(x)) for x in fruit_list if x in fruit_dict.keys()]
```

Something like that?

Result: `[('apple', 2), ('banana', 3), ('strawberry', 0), ('watermelon', 1), ('apple', 2), ('watermelon', 1)]`

Or `result = [fruit_dict.get(x) for x in fruit_list if x in fruit_dict.keys()]`

Result - `[2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1]`